# Prototypal inheritance and new keyword

Tags: javascript

In backbone.js under the inherits method, the authors does this:

```
var ctor = function() {};
// some other code ...

var child;
// some other code ...
ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
child.prototype = new ctor();
```

The above as I understand it is to allow the new object to inherit the prototypical chain of the parent. I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but in practice, is there a difference between the above and assigning the prototype directly?

```
child.prototype = parent.prototype
```

I understand that there exists this [[prototype]] object that cannot be accessed directly unless through the new keyword. However, given that most object declarations are of the form

```
var SomeObj = function() {};
SomeObj.prototype.test = function() { return "Hello World"; }
```

What would be the practical differences in the above prototype assignments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a prototype is an *instance* of the parent type. Using `child.prototype = parent.prototype` would set the child's prototype equal to the parent's prototype, rather than an prototypical instance of the parent.

Here's a **huge problem** that arises if you use `child.prototype = parent.prototype`: if you try to alter the child's prototype, you're also altering the parent's prototype, because they are the same object.

```
Child.prototype.childOnlyValue = 5;
// WARNING: Parent.prototype.childOnlyValue is now also 5,
//             because Parent.prototype === Child.prototype
```

Creating the new instance of the parent is absolutely necessary.  Otherwise, you'll have a flat prototype chain with a single shared prototype, so you'll have problems like the one I've outlined above.

Comment: I see. To think of it in terms of prototypes, does that mean that the `new` keyword actually creates a copy of the parent's prototype chain? 

In other words, when the `new` keyword is invoked, the resulting instance is a copy of all the objects in the class prototype?

Comment: No, the prototype chain isn't recreated.  When a new instance is created with `new`, the `__proto__` attribute of the new object is set to the appropriate prototype object.  So, in sum, prototype chains aren't copied for a new object; instead, new objects get a reference to the appropriate prototype chain (the `__proto__` element).  There is only copy of the one "prototype tree" (i.e., all existing prototype chains, rooted in `Object`).

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now. See below script (char limits) for how I arrived to the conclusion. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a script that describes the above situation

```
var x = {
    // do nothing
};

var a = function() {};

a.prototype = x;

var b = new a();
console.log("b.__proto__ is x? " + (b.__proto__ == x)); // true

var c = function() {};
c.prototype = new a();
console.log("c prototype.__proto__ is x? " + (c.prototype.__proto__ == x)); // true

var anotherFn = function() {
    // do nothing
};
c.prototype.aFn = anotherFn;

var d = new c();
console.log("d __proto__^2 is x?" + (d.__proto__.__proto__ == x)); // true
console.log("d __proto__.aFn is anotherFn? " + (d.__proto__.aFn == anotherFn)); // true
```