# Using InstanceOf with Prototypal inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, typechecking

I'm trying to use prototypal inheritance, but I'm having trouble.

This doesn't work

```
var Parent = function(){
}

var Child = function(){
    this.__proto__ = new Parent();
}

var child = new Child();

console.log(child instanceof Child) //logs false
```

But this does

```
var Parent = function(){
}

var Child = function(){

}
Child.prototype = new Parent();

var child = new Child();

console.log(child instanceof Child) // logs true
```

The only reason why I want the first option is so that I can leverage the parent's constructor. I'm guessing `this` is the problem, but I'm not that great at javascript. How do I make this work?

Comment: When you say `this.__proto__ = new Parent()` you're saying "Okay new object, stop being a `Child` and start being a `Parent` instead," so it's not surprising that the object is no longer and instance of Child.

Comment: @apsillers is that because of `this`? Why doesn't the second method do the same thing then? Is it because I am not in the scope of `new Child` when I set the prototype?

Comment: Ah, I understand your confusion now; I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi Josh, it's a little late but maybe the following answer can give you a better understanding of prototype (shared members) and `this` (instance members): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: but this is actually Classical Inheritance not Prototypal Inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do this is to `call` the `Parent` constructor on `this`:

```
var Child = function(){
    Parent.call(this);
}
```

That way, the `Parent` constructor code runs with its `this` set to the `this` in the `Child` constructor, but you don't change the `__prototype__` of `this`.

Your two examples do produce a `child` instance that is structurally the same. *However*, the main difference is that in your first example, `Child.prototype != child.__proto__`. Although it is true that `Child.prototype` and `child.__proto__` are both objects with a `__proto__` of `Parent.prototype`, they are not *the exact same* object, so `instanceof` fails.

You may *also* want to do `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` so that `Child` instances have access to `Parent`'s prototype method. (Currently you don't have any methods on `Parent.prototype`, but maybe you will someday.)

Comment: It is entirely my intention to have common methods on the Parent or its prototype

Comment: Don't I need to set the result of `Parent.call(this)` to something on Child? And, does `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` replace `Child.prototype = new Parent();`?

Comment: @JoshC. No, `Parent.call(this)` stands on its own, because it mutates `this`. The `Parent` constructor does things like `this.foo = 5`, so after `Parent.call(this)` completes, your `this` has a `foo` property.

Comment: Then how do I pass args to the parent constructor from the child? Do I simply list them after `this` like `Parent.call(this, arg0, arg1, etc.)`?

Comment: @JoshC. Yes, you should do `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` instead of `Child.prototype = new Parent();` Here's an example of why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20201556/710446. Basically, the `Parent` constructor might do things per-instance (like set a unique ID), and you don't want all your `Child` instances sharing a single instance ID.

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking part of my parent's common behavior but unique per instance data would be driven in part by args passed to the constructor. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @JoshC. Yes, that's the [correct way to use `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). You could also use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass in an array of arguments, like `Parent.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, arg3])`. This is especially handy if you want to pass in all of `Child`'s arguments to `Parent`, by doing `Parent.call(this, arguments)`.