# Inheritance of variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript

If I use prototypical inheritance in Javascript, the methods are available in subclasses but the members from parent are shared. Why is this?

For e.g., I am extending 2 data structure classes from my store.

```
function Store() {
    this._store = [];
    this._index = -1;
}

Store.prototype.addData = function (val) {
    this._index++;
    this._store[this._index] = val;
};

Store.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Store: [" + this._store + "]";
};

// inherits from Store
function DS1() {
}

DS1.prototype = new Store();
DS1.prototype.constructor = DS1;
```

Now if I use 2 instances of DS1, they are using the same store data. Why is that?

```
var ds1 = new DS1();
ds1.addData(2);
console.log(ds1.toString());  // Prints 2

var ds2 = new DS1();
ds2.addData(3);
console.log(ds2.toString()); // Prints 3

console.log(ds1.toString()); // Prints 3 and NOT 2.
```

Comment: *All instances* of DS1 are sharing the same data, because there's only one `DS1.prototype._store` , ever.

Comment: No. 2 Different data structures. In Java terms, both DS1 and DS2 extend Store and I expect both to have their own _store array.

Comment: @aspillers, removed the DS2 which caused confusion. So I have 2 instances of DS1. Why do they share the same data?

Comment: @apsillers "All instances of DS1 are sharing the same data, because there's only one DS1.prototype._store". Can you explain this more please? When I do DS1.prototype = new Store(); doesn't it mean whenever I do new DS1, all instances have their own _store?

Comment: No, because the `DS1` constructor doesn't set a `_store` property. Only the `Store` constructor does that, and you only call it one time, ever.

Comment: @apsillers, that helps! is there anyway else I can achieve different instances of _store or is that not recommended/easily possible in Javascript?.. Thanks just saw your answer.

Comment: If you'd like to know more about the workings of prototype and the role of the constructor function you can read about it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one reason why use of [`new` is discouraged for use with `prototype`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198267/why-is-the-use-of-constructors-discouraged-when-creating-prototypes). The problem is that a new unique `_data` array is created *only* when your `Store` constructor runs. Your `Store` constructor only runs *one time*, ever, in `DS1.prototype = new Store();` This means that all`new DS1()` instances share the same `_data` array.

Here's an relevant example adapted from a [different answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201017/how-should-you-inherit-from-eventemitter-in-node/20201556#20201556). Suppose each `Store` has a pseudo-unique, random `id` property:

```
var Store = function() {
    // each Store instance has a random id
    this.id = Math.random();
}
Store.prototype.addData = function() { /* ... */ }
```

Then, you want `DS1` to inherit from `Store`:

```
var DS1 = function() {
    this.something = 5;
}
DS1.prototype = new Store();  // this is bad

var ds1 = new DS1();
console.log(ds1.id);

var ds2 = new DS1();
console.log(ds2.id);  // same as ds1!
```

Bad news -- `DS1` instances all share the same `id` now! `DS1.prototype.id` is set once, ever, on the line `DS1.prototype = new Store();`, and that's where all `DS1` instances get their `id` from.

Instead, you want to run the `Store` constructor code each time you run the `DS1` constructor code, instead of just once when your set up the `DS1` prototype:

```
var DS1 = function() {
    Store.call(this);  // set parent constructor properties on `this` new DS1 obj
    //...
}

// DS1 prototype inherits from Store prototype, not Store instance
DS1.prototype = Object.create(Store.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

`This is because in Javascript object are not copied by value but only by reference`.Now, the prototypes of children (here ds1, ds2) and parents point to same object, when a child modifies the prototype, the parents get the changes and so do the siblings. `Inheritance in javascript` can be achieve by creating empty function F() setting its prototype to prototype of parent constructor as below.

```
    function extend(Child, Parent) {
var F = function () {};
F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
Child.prototype = new F();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.uber = Parent.prototype;
}
```

This way you can inherit by simply using `extend(ds1, Store)`; [Inheritance and prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: What is Uber here @Vivek? I am not able to get this pattern working. Anything else to add to extend?

Comment: Store.call(this); is required again here. Got it!

Answer (score 1):

Add `Store.call(this)` to your `DS1` "class". After that you can start assigning values for your `DS1` specific properties inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Sorin. As apsillers mentioned, I had to also use DS1.prototype = Object.create(Store.prototype);

Answer (score 1):

As it was said in comments, all childs uses the same object as a prototype. That is how prototypical inheritance works.

The prototype object in such kind of inheritance stands as a spare storage of methods and variables for child objects.

When you call/get a var from `d1` or `d2` it looks if they have `addData`. They haven't. Then js looks into __prototype. Hey, `new Store` is there! Does it have a `addData`? Yes! Calling it...

It's important, that `new Store` is called once, so a created object stands for all childs of your parent.