# To and form which objects do the events really go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, dom-events, eventemitter

I'm trying to understand the `EventEmitter` module in Node.js. Reading the [apidoc at nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events) tells me this:

> Functions can then be attached to objects, to be executed when an
> event is emitted. These functions are called listeners. Inside a
> listener function, this refers to the EventEmitter that the listener
> was attached to.

The thing is, when I play around a little with this I find that it, in my understanding, doesn't follow the doc.

```
var events = require('events');

function Person(nameInput){
    this.name = nameInput;
    this.sayMyName = function(preString){
        console.log(preString + this.name);
    }
}

Person.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();

var person1 = new Person("James");
var person2 = new Person("Daniel");

person1.addListener('sayit', function(){
    this.sayMyName("Hello ");
});

person2.addListener('sayit', function(){
    this.sayMyName("Hi ");
});

person1.emit('sayit');
```

---

```
//console prints out:
Hello James
Hi James
```

My question is. Given the docs saying `this refers to the EventEmitter that the listener was attached to` (person1 resp. person2 in my case), shouldn't the output of the program be like this?

> Hello James
> Hi Daniel

Comment: Where is your `person2.emit` call?

Comment: That's the thing! Both listeners to person1 and person2 responds to emissions from person1, and both in the context of person1. Which is the opposite of what the doc says.

Comment: Related: [How should you inherit from EventEmitter in node?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20201017/710446)

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem when you have *initialised* only (exactly) one `EventEmitter` for all your `Person` instances:

> ```
> Person.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();
> ```

That will create only one listener store which is *shared* amongst all instances - just as prototypes should work. See also [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572).

To make the inheritance correct, you need to do

```
function Person(nameInput){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.name = nameInput;
}

Person.prototype = Object.create(events.EventEmitter.prototype);
```

This does not *create* an `EventEmitter` for the prototype, but only inherits from it. Every `Person` instance will then initialise its own emitter (even if that would be done by `addListener` or `emit` automatically, [it's still a good thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791445/1048572)).