# Confusion about inheritance in javascript on the document with heading "Object.create()" at MDN

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been reading the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) document at Mozilla Developer Network. In this document, a way for inheritance is defined as follows:

```
// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

The question is, while assigning the Shape prototype to Rectangle prototype, why do I create a new Object as given in this code snippet? :

`Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);`

Why couldn't I assign the inheritance as this code snippet? :

`Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least closely related to) http://stackoverflow.com/q/10393869/710446

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because then anything you add to `Rectangle.prototype` will also be in `Shape.prototype`.
You'll also have the wrong `constructor` property.

You want `Rectangle.prototype` to inherit all members from `Shape.prototype`, but still be an independent object that can have its own members.