# Node.js: relationship of events.EventEmitter.call(this) and Obj.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;

Tags: javascript, node.js, function-prototypes

I'm learning Node.js and have some confusion about customized EventEmitter.
Here's the code:

```
var events = require("events");
function MyEmitter (name){
        this.name = name;
//      events.EventEmitter.call(this);
        this.emitEvent = function(){
                this.emit("Event1");
        }
}
//MyEmitter.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
MyEmitter.prototype         = events.EventEmitter.prototype;

function foo(){
        console.log("callback: " + this.name);
}

var obj = new MyEmitter("MyEmitter");
obj.on("Event1", foo);
obj.emitEvent();
```

There's two similar lines to inherit from EventEmitter;

```
//MyEmitter.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
    MyEmitter.prototype         = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

It seems both of these two expressions will work.
And I saw "The **proto** property is deprecated" from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Besides, if I comment out the

```
//      events.EventEmitter.call(this);
```

The code will also work.

I heard that call() is used as a constructor of EventEmitter,

```
//MyEmitter.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

and this line is used to copy all of the EventEmitter properties to the Door object.

So why do we have to copy the properties twice?

Could anyone tell me what's the difference between these expression?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Possibly related: [How should you inherit from EventEmitter in node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201017/how-should-you-inherit-from-eventemitter-in-node)

Comment: Definitely related: [Prototypal inheritance and new keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393869/prototypal-inheritance-and-new-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

```
MyEmitter.prototype         = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

You just assigned your class to have the same prototype as `EventEmitter`.

That means that anything you add to your prototype will actually be added to `EventEmitted.prototype`.

That's a very bad idea.

The correct solution is to call `Object.create()` to create a new object that inherits its prototype, as I explain in [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/).

Comment: It should be noted that the solution used throughout node core and many modules in npm is to use `util.inherits()`.

Comment: @mscdex: Which does exactly what my blog post describes.

Comment: That may be, but IMHO having this abstraction is nice in case of improved inheritance methods or possible language-related deprecation. Also it's shorter and a bit clearer as to what's happening when visually scanning code.

Comment: Yes, but it's also important to understand how it works.